# Dismiss UIAlertview programmatically in didReceiveLocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uilocalnotification

I am developing a application in iOS 7.1, that contains UILocalNotification. When my notification raise up, it goes to AppDelegate didReceiveLocalNotification delegate method. At the time my all screen closed and come to Notification screen [Which i designed for notification view] except UIAlertView.

If i use UIAlertView with delegate self, it will crash while press alertView button in Notification screen.

So how could i dismiss UIAlertView programmatically when i receive Notification.

Kindly help me to archive this.

Answer (score 1):

To dismiss it programmatically use this:

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```